# VACUUM and re-indexing in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-administration

I have automated the VACUUMING and re indexing for my PostgreSQL cluster running on same day.
what should we perform first to get more performance VACUUMING and re indexing?

please advice, thank you

Comment: What problem do you try to solve? We never reindex, no need for, and autovacuum is doing at least 90% of all the work.

Comment: You should not do either of these thinks without good reason.

Comment: I thought re indexing will provide good performance for select queries. Vacuuming will free up the space. I am doing these 2 tasks for weekly once for big tables .  is it not required?, please advice